# Equation Notation for Eco-Evolutionary Modelling

Tags: notation

Wondering if anybody could explain this equation notation to me? It's part of an eco-evolutionary model.

> $$x_{ij} = x_{base_j} + \sum_{k = 1}^L\sum_{u\in\lbrace M_{ik, 1}, M_{ik, 2}\rbrace}\varepsilon_u$$

Comment: There are 3 or 4 different notations in that expression. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: I understand that the value of X at trait j in individual i = baseline value of j + the sum of all values (sigma) from K to L...then beyond that I lose my way.